# Deeplinking android application with Get parameter

Tags: android, deep-linking

My requirement is to link my application with google playstore URL. So whenever application link 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=package-name
is clicked my app must be launched if installed in device.

In manifest I added:

```
 <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="play.google.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/store/apps/details"/>
```

As this link launches my app for other playstore links as well.

How can I add id=package-name parameter under data section?

Comment: As far as I know, App Links can only be defined against a base URL (query string parameters are not an option). Is there a reason why you need to do this on the Play Store URL itself, or could you detect whether the app is installed using another page and then redirect to the app (if installed) or the store (if not installed)?

Comment: Our app works like this way: Got a URL in whatsapp. On click of URL it hits my server. Javascript in web tries to launch app with deeplinking. After some time delay it redirects to playstore if app is not launched. So to full proof my redirection to app only, if its installed I wanted to deeplink the playstore URL.

Comment: I do not believe there is any way to accomplish this. On iOS, the equivalent Universal Links configuration also ignores URL query parameters, fyi. Fortunately this is likely to be an extreme edge case, since if the detection failed the first time then there is little chance it would succeed on the next attempt.